# BGE Game Camera

Tags: game-engine, camera

I was wondering if anyone knew how to setup something where whenever I press Play it would start me in the player camera without having to press 0 before hand. Even if lets say I was in Front view, if I pressed P it would send me to the camera, kinda like Cryengine or Unreal. Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: have an always sensor trigger a set camera actuator.

Answer (score 1):

As X-27 already mentioned - activate a scene actuator in set camera mode.

[image]